# Heading Link visual cue

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm wondering whether there is an good alternative visual cue for a hyperlinked heading. I'm looking for something other than an underline for practical and stylistic reasons. A different colour wouldn't work because the heading is separate from other text and so the cue would be meaningless. Short of making the heading pulse or have an arrow with a label saying "click me", I'm not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think of why you are linking the header. Do you want users to click it? Is it supposed to perform an action?

These are design decisions you need to make based on how you expect users to interact with your site.

For example, the question heading on Stack is a link, but it isn't underlined nor a different color. This is because the link isn't important - it's not trying to draw attention to itself.

If you're even thinking of going with a "click me" label or pulsing text, you'd probably be better of with a button. Links are for navigation, not for actions. Similarly, headings are for defining sections of text, not for navigation.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYnf2/).

```
This is a header - it sections off text:
<h1>Some Heading</h1>
<hr>
This is a button - it calls for action:
<button>Some Heading</button>
<hr>
This is a link - it navigates somewhere:
<a href="#">Some Heading</a>
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about a very simple one which doesn't detract from the text at all: the cursor (http://bit.ly/MKgo5Q)!

Comment: Ah, sure. I thought (when you were mentioning 'visual cues') that you wanted something that was noticeable without interaction. But of course the cursor is also a good way to provide hover feedback.